# Relationships not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

[Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ybr.jpg)Please help in finding the error.

I am new to the programming world and got stuck here.

> Error:System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is
>   not valid. Errors: The relationship 'ParadisModel.FK_Cart_Product' was
>   not loaded because the type 'ParadisModel.Product' is not available.
>   The following information may be useful in resolving the previous
>   error: The required property 'ID' does not exist on the type
>   'Product'. at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection
>   edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1
>   logLoadMessage) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataOptimization.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action
>   action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) at
>   ProductModel.InsertProduct(Product product) in
>   c:\Users\iconjamalay\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\WebSites\ODPshop\App_Code\Models\ProductModel.cs:line 16

Thanks

Comment: Provide the data model please.

Comment: I;ve included a link image above for models data.

Comment: I don't see all data models and DbContext but probably you need to add the Product entity in your DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

When I created new table “post” and gave foreign key relation to another “category” table after that run the custom tool by right click on edmx file. While running the application I got the following error. It was resolved by including post table foreign key relation to the category class.